# デバッグ中のAngularを、コンソールから操作したい

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, angular

例えばVueは、以下のようにして変数を書き換えて動作を確認できます。

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <title>vue-01-bind</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="example">
            <div>example-01 本文は二重中括弧 : {{ message }}</div>
        </div>
        <script>
            const example = new Vue({
                el: '#example',
                data: {
                    message: 'Hello Vue!'
                },
            });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Chrome F12 > Console で以下を実行

```
example.message = "change!!!";
```

同様のことをAngularでやりたい場合、どうやって対象のコンポーネントインスタンスを取得すればいいでしょうか？

【環境・状況】
Visual Studio Code 1.60.2　& 内蔵JS Debugger

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Angular CLI: 12.2.6
Node: 16.8.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 7.21.0
OS: win32 x64
ng serveされたhttp://localhost:4200/ 上のページ

【試したこと】

ng.getComponent($0); // nullが返ってくる
ng.getOwningComponent($0); // nullが返ってくる

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
Elementsでコンポーネントタグを選択してから、以下で行けました。
（例えば、app-rootタグや、router-outlet直後にいる個々のコンポーネントタグ）

```
let cmp = ng.getComponent($0);
```

また、Elementsで要素選択するのが面倒な場合は、タグさえ分かっていれば以下で可能でした。

```
// これでもOK
let cmp = ng.getComponent(document.getElementsByTagName('app-root')[0]);
```